# Java is denied permission to delete file it should have permission to delete

Tags: java, macos, file, unix, permissions

We're overriding the default account for the mac guest user at Berkeley Community Media, and I'm writing a Java program that will prepare the default user to be overridden via Terminal.

To use the program, the user must copy the edited default account's root directory into their desktop or similar, and use that file path as an argument. The program proceeds to delete a bunch of unnecessary folders and files from the Library folder, so that the account is ready to override the default template.

The program works when trying it on a test folder I created to test my code, but as soon as I attempt to use it in an actual account folder (on my desktop of course) It outputs "Failed to delete [name]", which is a println I wrote to signify a failed file.delete(), and the file isn't deleted.

If I add my own file and add it to the list of files to delete, it works though, which is strange.

Also, I'm not to sure what's causing this, but when I delete the file through Finder, it asks for administrator permission, even though I have read+write access, and the ls -l looks like this:

*drwxr-xr--+ 12 Sam54123  staff      408 Mar 10 00:21 Guest*

I'm not sure what that + is either, so if anyone could shed some light on the situation that would be appreciated. I'm pretty sure it's a problem with Unix, rather than my code.

Comment: Could you show us full folder and file permissions to both folders (the one that works and the one that doesn't)?

Answer (score 0):

`ls` manual of MacOS says:

> Otherwise, if the file or directory has extended security information (such as an access control list), the permissions field
>        printed by the -l option is followed by a '+' character.

and

> ```
>  -e      Print the Access Control List (ACL) associated with the file, if
>          present, in long (-l) output.
> ```